# Prove divergence means that for some k, $\{|X_n - X| > \frac{1}{k}\}$

Tags: probability, random-variable, measure-theory

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

What I tried:

I think the hint is equivalent to

$$\{\omega | X_n \rightarrow X\} = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \{\omega | \liminf_n [|X_n - X| \le \frac{1}{k}]\}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Important inequalities

Williams - Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

Deduced similarly:

(iii) If $\liminf x_n > z$, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n > z)$ eventually (that is, for infinitely many n)

(iv) If $\liminf x_n < z $, then

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (x_n < z)$ infinitely often (that is, for infinitely many n)

---

$$(\supseteq)$$

Let $\omega \in \Omega$

Suppose $\omega \in RHS$.

Then

$$\liminf_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \le \frac{1}{1}]$$

$$\liminf_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \le \frac{1}{2}]$$

$$\liminf_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \le \frac{1}{3}]$$

$$\vdots$$

Then, by 2, we have

$$\limsup_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)|] \le \frac{1}{1}$$

$$\limsup_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)|] \le \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\limsup_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)|] \le \frac{1}{3}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\to \limsup_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)|] \le 0$$

$$\to \limsup_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)|] = 0$$

$$\to \lim_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)|] = 0$$

$$\to \lim_n [X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)] = 0$$

$$\to \lim_n X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)$$

---

$$(\subseteq)$$

Let $\omega \in \Omega$

Suppose on the contrary that $\omega \in LHS$.

I guess $$\liminf X_n(\omega) = \limsup X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)$$

Suppose $\exists k \in \mathbb N$ s.t.

$$\liminf_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| > \frac{1}{k}]$$

$$\to \liminf_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| \ge \frac{1}{k+1}]$$

Then, by 4, we have

$$\liminf_n [|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)|] \ge \frac{1}{k+1}$$

$$\to [|\liminf_n X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)|] \ge \frac{1}{k+1}$$

$$\to [|X(\omega) - X(\omega)|] \ge \frac{1}{k+1}$$

$$\to 0 \ge \frac{1}{k+1}$$

$$\to 0 \ge 1 \ \unicode{x21af}$$

QED